# delete telegram channel users fails

Tags: telegram

I am trying to delete a user from a telegram private channel. I click on the user, then on the *delete* link, but I get no response and of course the user is not deleted. I have checked [the FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq_channels) which instructs to do what I have done, which seems to be seamless.

I am also trying to change the administrator and set admins but it does not work. As with my primary concern [the FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq_channels) says I should click on a user and set or unset admin privileges but there is no such menu.

Perhaps this is a temporarily failure? I have tried with opera, chrome and firefox with windows 10.

Comment: Please ask Telegram Support instead of asking here.

Comment: indeed, already asked before posting here

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for autoanswering. It looks like this has been solved as of today. It was possible to delete channel members via the app user interface. And now with the web.